# Understanding the purpose of generator functions

Tags: flutter, dart

I am learning about generator functions and in the documentation, generator functions are lazily evaluated but what is the benefit of this and why would you care? You will see this synchronous generator function:

```
Iterable<int> naturalsTo(int n) sync* {
  int k = 0;
  while (k < n) yield k++;
}
```

But what will be different if I do this?

```
Iterable<int> naturalsTo(int n) {
  List<int> numbers = [];
  for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
    numbers.add(i);
  }
  return numbers;
}
```

Both codes do exactly the same thing? Is there a memory advantage if I go for the generator function?

Comment: The second one allocates a new array, the first one doesn't. Imagine you get the data from a file or from network. You process it as it arrives, instead of waiting until you get all of it and then process.

Comment: ah I see, so the first example would be like youtube videos buffering, you watch as you download. instead of downloading the entire video like in the second example?

Comment: @ChristopherMoore right, but regardless if dart choose for me or not, the result is the same. I am trying to understand why I would prefer one over the other, thank you

Comment: Both codes are the same in the sense that they provide something you can iterate over and get (eventually) all the numbers to `n`. *How* each one does that is very different.

Comment: Calling the generator function takes O(1) time and O(1) space. Calling the regular function takes O(n) time and O(n) space. The generator lets you iterate, but not access arbitrary values without first iterating over all preceding values. The list lets you iterate, access arbitrary values, and do either of those two things any number of times without "using up" the list.

Answer (score 1):

> what will be the different if I do this?

The first one is a stream `sync*`, which means whenever `yield` called, it's subscriber receive values.

The second one is a normal method. It's caller has to wait until inner loop(in your case) completed.

Answer (score 0):

Generator functions add values as they are generated, while standard functions add values all at once: into the return object.

Generator functions release memory used to yield values after sending them to a consumer, unlike standard functions that have hold all values in memory to return a collection.

The `yield` keyword is what generates values on-demand.

```
Iterable<int> listTo(int n) { //Standard function
  List<int> numbers = [];
  for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
    numbers.add(i);
  }
  return numbers; //Adds values to the return object at once.
}
Iterable<int> countTo() sync* { //Generator function
  yield 0; //0 added to the return object and so on.
  yield 1; 
  yield 2;
  yield 3;
}

void main() {
  print(countTo());
  print(listTo(3));
}
```